# Getting Price of Custom Option that does not have values

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-options

I am trying to get at the prices for custom options that do not have predefined values. For example, you can have a checkbox custom option that has some option values and you would assign a price to each.

However, you might have a textarea (which obviously does not have predefined values). In admin, you can attach a price to that textarea.

My question: How do I get to that price. My preference would be with the SOAP v2 API; however, I am open to PHP code solutions as well as I would simply extend the core API.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I just found the necessary code snipped:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load('396');
$options = $product->getOptions();
foreach ($options as $option) {
    echo $option->getPrice();
    echo $option->getPriceType();

}
```